# How to run t-test on multiple pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, scipy

I want to write a code (with few lines) that runs t-test on `Product` and `Purchase_cost`,`warranty_years` and `service_cost` at the same time.

```
# dataset 

import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import ttest_ind

data = {'Product': ['laptop', 'printer','printer','printer','laptop','printer','laptop','laptop','printer','printer'],
        'Purchase_cost': [120.09, 150.45, 300.12, 450.11, 200.55,175.89,124.12,113.12,143.33,375.65],
        'Warranty_years':[3,2,2,1,4,1,2,3,1,2],
        'service_cost': [5,5,10,4,7,10,4,6,12,3]
    
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
```

code attempt for `Product` & `Purchase_cost`. I want to run t-test for `Product` & `warranty_years` and `Product` & `service cost`

```
#define samples
group1 = df[df['Product']=='laptop']
group2 = df[df['Product']=='printer']

#perform independent two sample t-test
ttest_ind(group1['Purchase_cost'], group2['Purchase_cost'])
```

Comment: what do you mean by "concurrently" and "efficiently"? Do you want to parallelize the computations? Is it really worth it (do you have very large data and actually run into efficiency issue?) or just premature optimization?

Comment: @mozway - I want a simple code instead of repeating the steps in my code attempt for `service_cost` and `warranty_years`. ignore parallelization and optimization

Comment: I see, then you can use vectorial code, or loop over the columns, see the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ttest_ind`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_ind.html) can work on 2D (ND) inputs:

```
cols = df.columns.difference(['Product'])
# or with an explicit list
# cols = ['Purchase_cost', 'Warranty_years', 'service_cost']

group1 = df[df['Product']=='laptop']
group2 = df[df['Product']=='printer']
out = pd.DataFrame(ttest_ind(group1[cols], group2[cols]),
                   columns=cols, index=['statistic', 'pvalue'])
```

If it wasn't, you could have used a dictionary comprehension looping over your columns:

```
out = pd.DataFrame({c: ttest_ind(group1[c], group2[c]) for c in cols},
                    index=['statistic', 'pvalue'])
```

Output:

```
           Purchase_cost  Warranty_years  service_cost
statistic      -1.861113        3.513240     -0.919464
pvalue          0.099760        0.007924      0.384738
```

##### generalization to more pairs

If you have more than just laptop/printer as products and want to compare all pairs, you could generalize with:

```
from itertools import combinations

cols = df.columns.difference(['Product'])

g = df.groupby('Product')[cols]

out = pd.concat({(a,b): pd.DataFrame(ttest_ind(g.get_group(a), g.get_group(b)),
                                     columns=cols, index=['statistic', 'pvalue'])
                 for a, b in combinations(df['Product'].unique(), 2)
                }, names=['product1', 'product2'])
```

Example output with an extra category (phone):

```
                             Purchase_cost  Warranty_years  service_cost
product1 product2                                                       
laptop   printer  statistic      -1.861113        3.513240     -0.919464
                  pvalue          0.099760        0.007924      0.384738
         phone    statistic      -1.945836        2.988072      2.766417
                  pvalue          0.109251        0.030515      0.039533
printer  phone    statistic      -1.286968        0.423659      1.893370
                  pvalue          0.239026        0.684528      0.100178
```

*If you have many combinations, note that you should likely post-process the data to account for [multiple testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons_problem).*